# How to add to a List and display images from Resource File

Tags: c#, winforms, embedded-resource

I am creating a BlackJack game and I'm currently having a problem displaying the card image needed on my list.
I have added all 52 card to my resource file and I can't seem to have them displayed in a PictureBox.

Am I going about the right way?

My `Card` class:

```
internal class Card
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public Card(int value, string name, string image)
    {
        Value = value;
        Name = name;
        Image = image;
    }
}
```

Main Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static List<Card> myListOfCards = new List<Card>();
    static List<Card> dealersHand = new List<Card>();
    static List<Card> playersHand = new List<Card>();

    private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clubs
        myListOfCards.Add(new Card(2, "Two of Clubs", "Resources._2C.png"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag this `asp.net`? That's quite unrelated -- You can use `Properties.Resources._2C` or `(Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_2C")` (if that's he name of the Resource). -- Where and how did you add these files? -- I suggest to use a satellite `dll` (a Library Project) that contains the images and exposes public static methods to retrieve resource data by name or index (or whatever).

Comment: @Jimi I tried to implement those two and I keep getting the error image on the assigned picture box...

Comment: @Jimi dealerBox.ImageLocation = myListOfCards[0].Image;
            dealerBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;

Comment: `ImageLocation`? You mean `dealerBox.Image = myListOfCards[0].Image;` -- Is the Image added correctly to the `Image` Property of your class object? -- If not, then specify how you added these files to the Project. -- Not clear how you relate a PictureBox to the class object that provides the Image or how you planned to show more than one card.

Answer (score 0):

I've spotted a potential issue. Your code uses `"Resources._2C.png"` as a literal, and the `Card` class deals with it as a string. One way or another an `Image` must be retrieved from the resources of the `Assembly` and I don't see any code that does that.

Try this change:

```
class Card
{
    // METHOD 1
    // CTor with Image
    public Card(int value, string name, Image image)
    {
        Value = value;
        Name = name;
        Image = image;
    }

    // METHOD 2
    // CTor with string
    // The `BuildAction` property for the image files must
    // be set to `EmbeddedResource` for this version to work.
    public Card(int value, string name, string resource)
    {
        Value = value;
        Name = name;
        Image = Image.FromStream(
           typeof(Card)
          .Assembly
          .GetManifestResourceStream(resource));
    }

    public int Value { get; }
    public string Name { get;  }

    // Try making this an Image
    public Image Image { get; }
}
```

In the `MainForm`:

The image can either be read from the `Resource` file by removing the quotes *and* the extension:

```
// METHOD 1
private void buttonCard1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var card = new Card(1, "AceOfDiamonds", Resources.AceOfDiamonds);
    pictureBox1.Image = card.Image;
}
```

*OR* if the string is used, it must be fully qualified:

```
// METHOD 2
private void buttonCard2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get full names of available resources
    Debug.WriteLine(
        string.Join(
            Environment.NewLine, 
            typeof(MainForm).Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()));

    var card = new Card(2, "EightOfSpades", "resources.Images.EightOfSpades.png");
    pictureBox1.Image = card.Image;
}
```

Gets this in the `PictureBox`:

[image: Card images graphic]

*FYI: Here are the available embedded resources listed by the `Debug.WriteLine`:*

[image: GetManifestResourceNames]

Comment: [clone this sample](https://github.com/IVSoftware/image-resources-from-resx.git)